# Struts2 : Interceptor gets called , but not the Action class

Tags: struts2

This is my struts.xml file. As you can see an action class and an interceptor are configured.

My question is that, the interceptor is being called, but not the action class.

(Where as in tutorials, I read that after interceptor is executed it calls the action class method)

Please see my code:

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="loginkiran" class="vaannila.MyLoginInterCeptor" />
        </interceptors>

        <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld" method="kiran">
            <interceptor-ref name="loginkiran" />
            <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**This is my Action class's kiran method**

```java
public class HelloWorld {

    public String kiran() {
        System.out.println("Hi inside the Kiran Method");

        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

========================

**This is my Interceptor class**

```java
public class MyLoginInterCeptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The server Port is"+str);

        return invocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything in the logs? Also, turn on `devMode` and set logging to DEBUG level.

Comment: Please post your actual "MyLoginInterCeptor", the one you posted str is not defined, and I assume Interceptor is com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor in which case you would need to implement the abstract methods destry() and init(). It does not hurt to leave the import statements in to be extra clear.

Comment: Works fine for me, btw, as-is, with the `destroy()` and `init()` methods as Quaternion mentioned, and removing the `str` from `intercept`. *Note:* interceptors must be thread-safe, so be careful where you get/set `str` in your actual interceptor.

Comment: Clearly not the actual configuration and/or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the INPUT result. Define it within struts.xml and direct to a page with

```
<s:actionerror/>
```

tag and you'll figure out what was going wrong. If that doesn't work, try this

```
   <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld" method="kiran">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginkiran" />
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/x.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: What does an input result have to do with it? The code works (with the fixes I mention in my comment).

Comment: you are right, input result has nothing to do with it. I suggested to use input result, because possible parameters issues may be present due to which the action is not called, which can easily be uncovered using input result and viewing the actionmessage, actionerror and fielderrors.

Comment: There couldn't be any validation errors in the posted code since neither the validation nor workflow interceptors are included in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the defaultStack.
Add `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>` , below your mentioned interceptor reference

Answer (score 0):

Please write `System.out.println(invocation.invoke());` and check what it returns. Add try/ catch block to your code it will give you an idea. I think it is failing in `invoke()` method.